# Typing Redux toolkit's store in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to get started using Redux in React + TypeScript so I am following the Redux Toolkit's tutorials and try implementing it in a sample app.

I am having a lot of difficulty with typings concerning the store and the `mappStateToProps` function parameters.

I configured the store with a slice as follows:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import linksReducer from '../features/links/linksSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    links: linksReducer,
  },
})

export default store
export type AppStore = typeof store
```

And I connected a component like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

import { AppStore } from '../../features/appStore'
import { deleteLink } from '../../features/links/linksSlice'

import LinkCard from './LinkCard'
import Link from '../../models/Link'
import EmptyList from './EmptyList'

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  links: state.links,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = { deleteLink }
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

const LinksGrid = (props: ConnectedProps<typeof connector>) => {
  //  ...
}

export default connector(LinksGrid)
```

As you can see, I used the `any` type for the first argument of the `mapStateToProps` function because I can't find out how I am supposed to type it. Using `any`, I have no problem running the application so I assume I only have a typing problem.

The official documentation of RTK gives only an example of using `combineReducers` instead of `configureStore`, and it uses TS's `ReturnType<T>` which can only work on function but of course the `store` variable is not a function so it doesn't work.
I have also read the Redux and React Redux documentation but I still can't figure what to do.

I am sure this is actually simple but here I am... Can anyone help me get that typing working?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the [Redux Toolkit Advanced Tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial) and [Usage with TypeScript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) docs pages show you how to do this correctly.

First, it's not the type of the *store* that's important here.  It's the type of the *store state*.

If you use `combineReducers()` yourself, you can define that type as:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    first: firstReducer,
    second: secondReducer,
});

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

However, since you're using the shorthand setup form by passing the slice reducers to `configureStore` (which calls `combineReducers()` internally), you can do the same thing by checking the return type of `store.getState` instead:

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        first: firstReducer,
        second: secondReducer,
    }

});

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Then, as shown in the docs, you can import the `RootState` type into your component file and use it as the type in your `mapState` function:

```
import {RootState} from "app/store";

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  links: state.links,
})
```

Comment: Oh so I was missing the `store.getState` because I use `configureStore` and not `combineReducers`. The docs should be updated to reflect that I think, because the walkthrough illustrates `configureStore` but then the TS section doesn't explicit the fact that you then need the store type. I'll admit it's only logical but as a beginner in Redux I wasn't comfortable enough to get that on my own :-/
Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, to re-emphasize: what matters is _the type of the state object_.  There's really three ways to define that: 1) hand-define it yourself; 2) Infer it from the return type of the root reducer; 3) Infer it from the return type of `store.getState()`.  Now that you mention it, I'm not sure we mention the third option, because the docs show using `combineReducers()` yourself vs passing the slice reducers to `configureStore()`.

Comment: this does not work `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;` get only the keys correctly but not the types, all types are `never` for me

Comment: @KristiJorgji : best bet is to file a new question and show your current code, especially where you're importing the reducers and setting up the store.  Can also ask over in the Reactiflux Discord as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works me:

```
store?: EnhancedStore<{ default: RootState }, AnyAction, [ThunkMiddleware]>;
```

additionally i have added `redux-thunk` for `ThunkMiddleware`